# MS Excel Dynamic Worksheets List

Tags: excel, dynamic

I'm trying to make dynamic product list linked to worksheet dynamically

I want to make a list of product and every product having its own worksheet for more information about the product

I could do it Manually this way to link each product in the list

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#",A2,"!A1"),"View Product")
```

But the problem with it, that I would have to change the name of the worksheet and in the cell for it to work.. which is not so nice as I want it more dynamic
for example if I delete/update a product from the list the worksheet would remain the same.

So how can I make a hyperlink list to the worksheets and in case i delete a product from the list the worksheet gets deleted too or updated if the name of the product was changed

Comment: You'd like to delete a worksheet, based on whether a cell was deleted? Careful there, with VBA there's no practical way to Undo - so that sheet will be gone forever.  Could you perhaps show some sample data, and what you expect? You may be able to do something with `Indirect()`, or some way to make your formula more dynamic.

Comment: Im new to excel.. all I want to do is having a dynamic product list which links to a new page or a popup where i can add more details about the product.. i have no clue how to achieve this basic stuff on excel

Comment: So in your "Sheet1", a cell could say "Fruit". When you click "Fruit", you want it to take you to a sheet called "Fruit"?  Or, you click "Fruit", and a popup asks for "What kind of fruit", where the user puts in an answer, and that gets added to a list in a sheet called "Fruit"?  Could you post a sample before/after, so we could get a better idea?

Comment: say I have a list of all my products in "sheet1" when i click on one product item name i want a new page to open up with full product description!

and if i delete a product item from the list the related worksheet would get deleted as well..

if there are other ways to archive this without worksheets that would be fine too

Comment: You'll need to use VBA - start with the macro recorder to see how to select cells/delete sheets.  What happens if you add a new product item, that doesn't have a sheet? Do you want one to be created?

Comment: yes i want it to be created

Comment: is there a way to achieve this without sheets? meaning can i have a list of my products linked to the full product details without worksheets?